# Move divs from a list to another position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of items that I'm generating with ng-repeat, that looks something like this

```
...
<div class="a">
  <div>
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div>
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

I want to move all divs with class="b" outside their parent div with class="a", something like this.

```
...
<div class="a">
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="b"></div>

<div class="a">
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="b"></div>
...
```

I'm currently trying something with jQuery

```
$(".b").insertAfter(".a")
```

It just ends up generating a bunch of divs with class="b" for every div with class="a"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.each()` to traverse each `.b`

```
$(".b").each(function(){
   $(this).insertAfter($(this).closest(".a"))
})
```

In your code

`$(".b").insertAfter(".a")`

the `$(".b")` finds all the divs with class = `"b"` in the DOM and inserts it after each `.a`